# What is the best way to store resources in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift, file, directory

I have a folder with different regions in it, and inside this I have other folders with files. However, coming from Java, I am unsure how to store and access this data in Xcode using Swift for an iOS application. Would I be able to copy and paste a pre-made file from OS X into the project and access it? Or is there a better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the directory structure as folder references, not as groups. Groups get flattened by the compiler, but directory structures are preserved. Then you would need to use NSFileManager to reference the files at runtime.

This assumes you wouldn't be better served by converting the data into an iOS-friendly format like plist and localizing it.